# Win8 Metro (JS/HTML5) - Video not visible after page navigation

Tags: javascript, html, video, singlepage, single-page-application

I'm working on a media playback app that has two navigatable pages. I would like to store the video object so that if the user navigates away from the video page and then returns, the same object is loaded into the div and the user can simply pick up where they left off.

My problem: When the user returns to the video page, the video element reloads from scratch and I can't load it with the pre-existing video data. As a result, there is no video visible on the screen. My player controls, however, are tied to the original video object and continue to work as expected.

I'm new to these languages so any advice would be a great help. I can't figure it out for the life of me.

Here's the code. I initialize mediaSession and the flags in another script so they persist during page navigation.

**The player page HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>homepage</title>

    <!-- WinJS references -->
    <link href="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/css/ui-dark.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/base.js"></script>
    <script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/ui.js"></script>

    <link href="/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/pages/mediacontent/mediacontent.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!--    <script src="/js/appData.js"></script> -->
    <script src="/pages/mediacontent/mediacontent.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="body_div">
        <header id="header_titlearea">
            <h1 class="win-type-ellipsis">
                <img src="/images/logo.png" /><span> Decoder Sample App</span>
            </h1>
        </header>
       <div id="article_maintext">
           <video id="playbackVideo" height="100%" preload="auto">
           <!--<video id="Video1" height="100%" preload="auto" >-->
                    <!--<source src="/media/demo.mp4" />-->
           </video>
        </div>

         <footer id="footer">
             <br />
             <input type="range" class="s_Class" id="s_Seek" value="0"><br />
             <button class="action secondary" id="b_playFromFile">File Picker</button>
             <button class="action secondary" id="b_playbackPause">Play</button>
             <button class="action secondary" id="b_playbackStop">Stop</button>
             <button class="action secondary" id="b_playbackRewind">Rewind</button>
             <button class="action secondary" id="b_playbackForward">Forward</button>
             <button class="action secondary" id="b_playbackMute">Mute</button>
             <button id="navButton" class="navButton" title="Nav" >About</button><br />
             <p id="outputtext">debug monitor</p>
         </footer>
      </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**The player page JS (excerpt):**

```
(function f() {
    "use strict";

    WinJS.UI.Pages.define("/pages/mediacontent/mediacontent.html", {
        ready: function(element, options) {
            if (mediaSession.navflag === false) {
                mediaSession.vid = WinJS.Utilities.query("#playbackVideo")[0];
                mediaSession.vid.src = "/media/demo.mp4";
                document.getElementById('outputtext').innerHTML = "new mediaSession set!"
            } else if (mediaSession.navflag === true) {
                if (mediaSession.pauseflag === false) {
                    //mediaSession.vid.play();
                }
                document.getElementById('outputtext').innerHTML = "existing mediaSession!"
                *-Here is where I need help-*
                mediaSession.navflag = false;
            }
...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After a few false leads, I figured out how to swap out the reloaded video element with my video data, using the replaceChild() method.

the new javascript looks like this:

```
  (function f() {
    "use strict";

    WinJS.UI.Pages.define("/pages/mediacontent/mediacontent.html", {
        ready: function(element, options) {
            if (mediaSession.navflag === false) {
                mediaSession.vid = WinJS.Utilities.query("#playbackVideo")[0];
                mediaSession.vid.src = "/media/demo.mp4";
                document.getElementById('outputtext').innerHTML = "new mediaSession set!"
            } else if (mediaSession.navflag === true) {
                if (mediaSession.pauseflag === false) {
                    //mediaSession.vid.play();
                }
                document.getElementById('outputtext').innerHTML = "existing mediaSession!"
                var mediaParent = document.getElementById("article_maintext");
                mediaParent.replaceChild(mediaSession.vid, mediaParent.firstElementChild);
                mediaSession.navflag = false;
            }
...
        }
    }
}
```